# How to center an absolute positioned dynamically created div

Tags: html, css

I am creating the following div in `C#` code behind but was not able to `position` it in the `center` of the screen. anyone with a suitable answer is appreciated.

```
<div class="rect" style="top:" + (rectangles.ElementAt(i).Y + 50).ToString() + "px;left:" + (rectangles.ElementAt(i).X + 50).ToString() + "px;width:" + (rectangles.ElementAt(i).Width - 1).ToString() + "px;height:" + (rectangles.ElementAt(i).Height - 1).ToString() + "px;border-color:Black;text-shadow:3px 3px Black;border-width:3px;border-style:solid;border-collapse:seperate;position:absolute;background-color:#" + rectangles.ElementAt(i).Slice.Elements.ElementAt(0).color.ToString() + ";vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;font-family:Arial;font-size:48px;color:White;font-weight:bold;display:table-cell;" ><div style="position: relative;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);"><span>" + rectangles.ElementAt(i).Slice.Elements.ElementAt(0).Symbol + "</span><br/><span>" + rectangles.ElementAt(i).Slice.Elements.ElementAt(0).AverageMC + "%</span></div></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to center a div created dynamically with position absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35696003/how-to-center-a-div-created-dynamically-with-position-absolute)

Answer (score 0):

1. one way to do this is set the width then use  `margin: 0 auto;`

`<style>
    div {
      width: 360px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    } 
</style>`

2. another way to center a div by css is

`<style>
    div {
      width: 360px;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      float:none;
    } 
</style>`

use id and class with `div` otherwise it will apply to all div