# how to center a div created dynamically with position absolute

Tags: html, css

```
str.Append("<div class=\"rect\" style=\"top:" + (rectangles.ElementAt(i).Y + 50).ToString() + "px;left:" + (rectangles.ElementAt(i).X + 50).ToString() + "px;width:" + (rectangles.ElementAt(i).Width - 1).ToString() + "px;height:" + (rectangles.ElementAt(i).Height - 1).ToString() + "px;position:absolute;\"</div>");
```

I am creating this div and more divs that has been positioned absolute and then send the created html to another div(container). So that it creates a map the image is attached

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. can you decribe it with more details?

Comment: Please refer to the image...I have created many divs and inorder to create a treemap I have put position attribute of the divs to absolute. This would create an image as shown in the picture .I am using a container div and then sends the created html to the container div using .html() property...Now how would I center the position of the container div.

Comment: Do you want to center the wrapper div to the center? Or all the content (with the form)?

Comment: all the content with the form...the container div is

Comment: <div id="container" runat="server" style="width: 360px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
            float: none;text-align:center;">
        </div>

Comment: Can you create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) with this html (It's suppose to be easy) ? If you will do so, I can show you how to center it.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose your dynamic `<div>` inside a parent `<div>` wide and tall **0 pixels** and absolutely positioned at the center of the page with `left: 50%; top: 50%;`

***CSS***:

```
.bd_container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}    

#bigdiv1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px; /* Static height */
  width: 200px; /* Static width */
  background: blue;
  left: -100px;
  top: -100px;
}

#bigdiv2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: orange;
}
```

***HTML*** with static dimensions:

```
<div class="bd_container">
  <div id="bigdiv1"> <!-- Replace with your div -->
    <strong>Div 1</strong>
    <br /> With static dimensions and centered
  </div>
</div>
```

***HTML*** with dynamic dimensions:

```
<div class="bd_container">
  <div id="bigdiv2"> <!-- Replace with your div -->
    <strong>Div 2</strong>
    <br /> With dynamic dimensions and centered
  </div>
</div>
```

To positionate your dynamic `<div>` you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)'s [`css()` function](http://api.jquery.com/css/) like this:

```
var d2_width = parseInt($("#bigdiv2").css("width")) / 2;
var d2_height = parseInt($("#bigdiv2").css("height")) / 2;

$("#bigdiv2").css({
  "left": "-" + d2_width + "px",
  "top": "-" + d2_height + "px"
});
```

And here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/CliffBurton/3jhn41a7/1/) for you